# Count first occurence in a table not duplicates

Tags: php, mysql

I've produced a table in PHP to display the submission of evidence by students on a course.

The students make a submission to indicate which criteria their files match. It's basically a table with files listed down the left and criteria listed across the top. The student ticks come criteria for each file.

I then want to count which criteria are met and which aren't. Basically which columns have ticks and which don't.

It's easy to count all the ticks in a table, but I'm struggling to work out how to count distinct ticks by column in the table.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add details of how you're storing the data? The output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE` would be ideal

Comment: It is not very clear what kind of results you want to get. I made some wild guesses and wote an answer, but more specific information would be great.

Comment: Hope this image claries slightly. I'm looking for which criteria have been claimed. [link]http://citybit.southampton-city.ac.uk/example.PNG in this example I'm looking for 4 to be returned.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your scema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the not matched criteria is a null value then this will do:

```
select student, 
    count(crit1) > 0 as crit1, 
    count(crit2) > 0 as crit2 
from submission
group by student
order by student
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
  COUNT(DISTINCT ...) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table like (of course names in place of CritX). Also assume that non-ticked critria wull have a `NULL` value:

```
submission (fileanme, crit1, crit2, crit3, critN)
```

then you can check which critera have and have not been claimed by:

```
SELECT MAX(crit1) AS crit1, MAX(crit2) AS crit2 FROM submission;
```

You can get the number of categories whith ticked values:

```
SELECT MAX(crit1) + MAX(crit2) AS number FROM submission;
```